# Finding out the previous index value of a value in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For a column "stock" in a pandas dataframe, I want to add a column called last_index which gives the value of the index value before for a given Stock:

Input:

```
           Stock
02/10/17    IBM
02/10/17    Apple
02/10/17    Google
02/10/17    Microsoft
02/10/17    Lenova
02/10/17    Nintendo
02/10/17    Sony
02/10/17    Toshiba
03/10/17    IBM
03/10/17    Apple
03/10/17    Google
03/10/17    Microsoft
03/10/17    Lenova
03/10/17    Nintendo
03/10/17    Sony
03/10/17    BMW
03/10/17    Mercedes
04/10/17    Toshiba
```

Output:

```
               Stock    Last_index
02/10/17    IBM 
02/10/17    Apple   
02/10/17    Google  
02/10/17    Microsoft   
02/10/17    Lenova  
02/10/17    Nintendo    
02/10/17    Sony    
02/10/17    Toshiba 
03/10/17    IBM         02/10/17
03/10/17    Apple       02/10/17
03/10/17    Google      02/10/17
03/10/17    Microsoft   02/10/17
03/10/17    Lenova      02/10/17
03/10/17    Nintendo    02/10/17
03/10/17    Sony        02/10/17
03/10/17    BMW 
03/10/17    Mercedes    
04/10/17    Toshiba     02/10/17
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Is that date column in the index?

Comment: will you ever have the same Stock listed more than twice?

Comment: Not for the same date

Comment: but for different dates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can using *[shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)*

```
df['New']=df.reset_index().groupby('Stock')['index'].shift().values
df
Out[472]: 
              Stock       New
02/10/17        IBM       NaN
02/10/17      Apple       NaN
02/10/17     Google       NaN
02/10/17  Microsoft       NaN
02/10/17     Lenova       NaN
02/10/17   Nintendo       NaN
02/10/17       Sony       NaN
02/10/17    Toshiba       NaN
03/10/17        IBM  02/10/17
03/10/17      Apple  02/10/17
03/10/17     Google  02/10/17
03/10/17  Microsoft  02/10/17
03/10/17     Lenova  02/10/17
03/10/17   Nintendo  02/10/17
03/10/17       Sony  02/10/17
03/10/17        BMW       NaN
03/10/17   Mercedes       NaN
04/10/17    Toshiba  02/10/17
```

Comment: Another one of those Pandas functions that are super helpful that you don't know is there! Wen, can you add the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to your answer?

Comment: @MattR Yes you are right , I should added at beginning . :-)